# Why my ccdf plot starts in 0.4 instead of 1?

Tags: r, statistics

I have used the codes posted by community to plot a ccdf in R. in many cases it works fine however for the following data it is ploting ccdf plot starting from 0.4 instead of starting from 1; can someone please help?

```
x = c(50.76535,54.89802,74.12376,72.67228,50.76535,50.76535,50.76535,50.76535,50.76535,50.76535,72.67228,59.54455,72.67228,72.67228,72.67228,50.76535,50.76535,72.20198,50.76535,89.10891,50.76535,72.67228,50.76535,72.20198,50.76535,50.76535,50.76535)

plot(sort(x) , 1-ecdf(x)(sort(x) ), xlab = "x = log mean rain", ylab = "P(X > x)", pch = 1
     , ylim = c(0,1),t='b', log = 'x')
```

[image]

Comment: Note what is being represented on the y axis. Now count what proportion of your values are the smallest value.

Comment: Dason, in my opinion, the y-axis is the probability of X > x meaning that as all values are bigger than 50 the probability should be 1 as this is the case with ccdf plots. isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *ecdf* starts at 0. It is right-continuous, and it jumps at every data point. That is, it is equal to 0 before `min(x)`, and it has its first jump at `min(x)`:

```
x <- c(50.76535,54.89802,74.12376,72.67228,50.76535,50.76535,50.76535,50.76535,
       50.76535,50.76535,72.67228,59.54455,72.67228,72.67228,72.67228,50.76535,
       50.76535,72.20198,50.76535,89.10891,50.76535,72.67228,50.76535,72.20198,
       50.76535,50.76535,50.76535)
Fn <- ecdf(x)

Fn(min(x) - 1)
# 0
Fn(min(x))
# 0.5555556
```

The *ecdf* as well as its complementary function are *step functions*. When you do *ecdf(x)* you get a step function. To define the complementary *ecdf*, you have to use `stepfun`:

```
jumps_at <- sort(unique(x))
CFn <- stepfun(jumps_at, c(1, 1-Fn(jumps_at)))

plot(CFn, xlab = "x = mean rain", ylab = "P(X > x)", 
     verticals = FALSE, pch = 19, ylim = c(0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks; I've only used pch = 1 to connect the lines.